# Exporting web scraping into csv file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, export-to-csv

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.cbssports.com/nba/stats/playersort/nba/year-2019-season-preseason-category-scoringpergame")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for record in soup.find_all('tr'):
    try:
        print(record.contents[0].text)
        print(record.contents[6].text)
        print(record.contents[7].text)
        print(record.contents[8].text)
        print(record.contents[9].text)
        print(record.contents[10].text)
        print(record.contents[12].text)
        print(record.contents[13].text)
        print(record.contents[14].text)
        print(record.contents[15].text)
    except:
        pass
    print('\n')

def scrape_data(url):

    response = requests.get("https://www.cbssports.com/nba/stats/playersort/nba/year-2019-season-preseason-category-scoringpergame", timeout=10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    table = soup.find_all('table')[1]

    rows = table.select('tbody > tr')

    header = [th.text.rstrip() for th in rows[1].find_all('th')]

    with open('statsoutput.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(header)
        for row in rows[1:]:
            data = [th.text.rstrip() for th in row.find_all('td')]
            writer.writerow(data)


if __name__=="__main__":
    url = "https://www.cbssports.com/nba/stats/playersort/nba/year-2019-season-preseason-category-scoringpergame"
    scrape_data(url)
```

iv'e been trying to export the stats from this web page to a `csv file`.
when i'm running my code, the first part works fine and retrieves the data i want.
but the function can't export it in to a `csv file` and iv'e been getting this error:

```
table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and i'm not really sure why.

Comment: There's no second element in your table, so `table = soup.find_all('table')[1]` raises an error. To make it work, replace it by `soup.find_all('table')[0]`. Then you will have 67 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because this site has just one `<table />` html element. So `soupe.find_all()` is returning a list with length 1. You might solve this error doing `soupe.find_all('table')[0]` or, in a clean way, `soup.table`.

I also checked and tested your code and recommend this:

```
table = soup.table
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

Everything will works fine after these changes. You can check this code runing [here](https://repl.it/repls/OpenFloweryPaint). Hope it helps.